# How do I serialize a struct of 8bit integers for socket programming?

Tags: c++, sockets, serialization, struct

I have a struct that has 5 unsigned 8 bit integers that mimics a frame with 5 packets. After researching, I know need to serialize the data, field by field, especially since I am sending from a Windows machine to a Linux machine and back.

here is my struct:

```
typedef struct pressure{
    UINT8       a;
    UINT8       b;
    UINT8       c;
    UINT8       d;
    UINT8       e;
}pressure;
```

The issue is I cant use htons() since my members must be 8 bits. How do I manually serialize this? It would be greatly appreciated if you could provide a short code sample that shows how to serialize and what to pass to send().

Answer (score 3):

You can either write each individual byte using [`ostream::put`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/put/), or - if you've ensured they're contiguous in memory in `pressure` (which will be done on every compiler I've ever used without you doing anything actively) - write the lot of them using [`ostream::write`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/), as in:

```
my_ostream.write(static_cast<const char*>(&my_pressure.a), 5);
```

That said, consider keeping the values in an array so you're guaranteed they're contiguous in memory.

You don't need `htonX` / `ntohX` etc. - they're for normalising/denormalising *multi-byte* integer representations, which you don't have here.

Answer (score 0):

Just write it if you are sending from an Intel x86 based machine to another Intel x86 machine (which most linuxes are).

If however you plan to send it to a machine based on another processor the safest thing is to just send ASCI characters so something like:

```
 char[] buffer = sprintf("|%03d|%03d|%03d|%03d|%03d|",a,b,c,d,e);
```

Would give you a fixed length string readable by any machine. Its a good idea to have some sort of field separator (the "|" in this case) to help the receiver verify the string has not been garbled by an unreliable network.

Comment: uint8s are the same on all computers, there is no danger of them being misinterpreted.

Comment: Certainly different on DEC VAX !

Comment: Different how?  Would that difference be visible to a program sending 8-bit values to a VAX over a TCP/IP network?

Comment: @Jeremy -- ah you are probably write its the byte order that weird on DEC  cpus.